# ls option to cancel '-h'

Tags: ls

I aliased `ll` to `ls -alh`. Is there an option to cancel the `-h` temporarily, so I can do `ll -?` instead of `ls -al`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Adding `--block-size=1` should do what you are looking for if your `ls` supports it, although just typing `ls -al` is probably easier...

Answer (score 0):

Try using `/bin/ls` or `/usr/bin/ls`. That would get rid of all the flags altogether. So you probably wanted this:

```
/bin/ls -al
```

Answer (score 0):

Why not `unalias ll` and write a script called `ll`. It could look something like

```
=========
#!/usr/bin/bash

if [ $1 ]; then
     ls -al
else
     ls -alh
fi    
====
```

`ll -` would result  in a `ls -al` and with the `-` it would be a `ls -alh`.